# SQL YTD calculations adding periods without postings

Tags: query, sql-server-2017, aggregate, running-totals

I have a query which give me the YTD figures per company (client), account, IC and period for the periods in which financial postings have been performed. The table where I get this from is AAGCONSO which is a balance table of all the accounts, per client, period and IC.

```
SELECT        * FROM  (SELECT        client, account, IC, period, SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY client, account, IC, LEFT(period, 4)
                         ORDER BY client, account, IC, period) AS YTD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client, account, IC, period ORDER BY client, account, IC, period ASC) AS RowYTD FROM            (SELECT        t .client AS client, t .dim1 AS account, CASE WHEN t .dim2 IN ('10', '11', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '50', '60') THEN t .dim2 ELSE '' END AS IC, t .dim2, t .period AS period, SUM(t .amount) 
                                                AS amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t .client, t .dim1, LEFT(period, 4)
                      ORDER BY t .client, t .dim1, LEFT(period, 4) DESC) AS Row FROM            aagconso t WHERE        t .period >= 201853 AND client IN ('10', '11', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '50', '60') AND t .dim1 = '111110' GROUP BY t .client, t .dim1, t .dim2, period, t .amount HAVING        SUM(t .amount) <> 0) AS CTE2) X WHERE        RowYTD = 1 strong text ORDER BY 1 DESC Offset 0 Rows
```

This gives me the YTD amounts in the following table

[image]

The totals are correct, however I want to have the periods in which no postings have been performed included with the YTD amount of previous period.

I have another table with all possible accounting periods

```
SELECT acc_period FROM dbo.PBAP_GL_PERIODS
```

Which gives me this :
[image]

How do I get a full YTD table including the periods from table B for which there are no postings in table A? I probably need to use a cross apply or join but I really do not see where I get this ...

So for example Table A for account 111110 in client 10 gives me this

| Client | Account | Period | Amount | RowYTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 111110 | 202012 | 1325925.000 | 1 |

And I want to have this

| Client | Account | Period | Amount | RowYTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 111110 | 202000 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202001 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202002 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202003 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202004 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202005 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202006 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202007 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202008 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202009 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202010 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202011 | 0.000 | 1 |
| 10 | 111110 | 202012 | 1325925.000 | 1 |

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please add content to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example), like table DDL, sample data, and ideally a fiddle.

Comment: Hello, I am pretty new to this. Can you please explain me in detail what you need? how doe the fiddle work?

Comment: The link explains it in detail.

Comment: OK so I am creating my base table now in the SQL fiddle. How do you get access to that data?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0211c/2/0

Comment: The first table gives the Mtd amounts. The 2nd table all periods. I need to have the Ytd by client, dim1,dim2,period including for the periods which are not included in the 1st table